# When binding constructor getting an error: missing 'typename' prior to dependent type name in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

How to bind a constructor in C++?

In one class, I have template class with constructor like as shown below:

```
namespace EMRProcess
{
template<typename T>
    class CEMRImpl
    {

CEMRImpl(EMRProcessSR::CWebHandler<T>*  pHandler_, 
                            CSocketRemover* pSocketRemover, const std::string& strID, const std::string& strNo);

};
}
```

From another class, I am trying to bind the constructor like as shown below:

```
m_pMyObj->processEvent(EVT_MED, strTestId,
                                           std::bind(&EMRProcess::CEMRImpl<T>::CEMRImpl,
                                                     this,
                                                     this,
                                                     strID,
                                                     strNo));
```

**When compiling i am getting an error: missing 'typename' prior to dependent type name 'EMRProcess::CEMRImpl::CEMRImpl'**

Could someone please help me on this?

Comment: Does following help: `std::bind(&typename EMRProcess::CEMRImpl<T>::CEMRImpl, ...);`?

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot done

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are attempting to do with `std:::bind()`'ing a constructor will *never* work as-is, as it is *illegal* to take the address of a constructor. But a lambda can be used anywhere that `std::bind()` can be used (in fact, a lambda is almost always preferred over `std::bind()`), so have a lambda call the constructor normally and return the new object, eg:

```
m_pMyObj->processEvent(EVT_MED, strTestId,
    [&, this](){ return EMRProcess::CEMRImpl<T>(this, this, strID, strNo); }
);
```

Comment: Thank you @Remy Lebeau for the solution.

Answer (score 3):

You could implement a static member function that creates instances:

```
static auto create(
        CWebHandler<T>* pHandler, 
        CSocketRemover* pSocketRemover, 
        const std::string& strId, 
        const std::string& strNo) 
{
    return CEMRImpl<T>(pHandler, pSocketRemover, strId, strNo);
}
```

Based on that you could use bind to create the callable:

```
static auto createFactory(
        CWebHandler<T>* pHandler, 
        CSocketRemover* pSocketRemover, 
        const std::string& strId, 
        const std::string& strNo) 
{
    return std::bind(create, pHandler, pSocketRemover, strId, strNo);
}
```

Or you could just use a lambda as mentioned by Remy Lebeau:

```
auto task_factory = [] { return EMRProcessSR::CEMRImpl<int>(pHandler, pSocketRemover, "foo", "bar");};
```